# Proof of the formula for dimension of moduli of stable vector bundles on smooth curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, vector-bundles

Let $C$ be a smooth curve of genus $g \ge 2$ over an algebraically closed field of positive characteristic. If I understand correctly, the dimension of the moduli space of vector bundles on $C$ of rank $r$ and degree $d$ is given by $r^2(g(C)-1)+1$. Can someone suggest me a reference for the proof of this fact.

Comment: Any book on vector bundles on curves: for instance "Lectures on Vector Bundles" by Le Potier, CUP.

Comment: Thank you. I am a little confused though. Le Potier in Theorem 8.3.2 states that **if** the moduli space is non-empty then its dimension is $r^2(g-1)+1$. May be I am reading the statement wrong but isnt it true if $r^2(g-1)+1>0$ then the moduli space is non-empty?